# How to insert a Uppercase T between date and tile using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

Can't get my XSLT convertions to work, I'm trying to add / insert a uppercase T in startdate between date and time in the XML file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<callinfo>
<startdate>2014-04-25 12:18:19</startdate>
<duration>20</duration>
<local>xxxxxxxxxxx</local>
<remote>xxxxxxxxxxx</remote>
<local_name></local_name>
<remote_name></remote_name>
<direction>0</direction>
<data></data>
<id>20140425_121819_x0003</id>
<recording>20140425_121819_x0003.wav</recording>
<location>//recordit_server/mobilkald/20140425_121819_x0003.wav</location>
<errormsg></errormsg>
</callinfo>
```

The XSLT script I´m trying to get to work is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Call xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Data>
                <time_offset>
                    <xsl:number value="0"/>
                </time_offset>
                <audio><audio_segement>
                        <channel_id>0</channel_id>
                        <recording_order>1</recording_order>
                        <audio_url>
                    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/location"/>
                        </audio_url>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="callinfo/startdate"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="StartTime"/>
                                                <Duration>
                        <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/duration"/>
                        </Duration>
                    </audio_segement>
                </audio>
                <direction>
                    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/direction"/>
                </direction>
                <ani>
                    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/local"/>
                </ani>
                <dnis>
                    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/remote"/>
                </dnis>
                <unique_identifier>
                    <xsl:value-of select="callinfo/startdate"/>
                </unique_identifier>
            </Data>
        </Call>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="callinfo/startdate">
        <StartTime>

             <xsl:variable name="startTimeSize" select = "string-length(.)"/>
            <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize = 19">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>.00+00:00
            </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize = 33">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,0,24)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,28,7)"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize != 33 and $startTimeSize != 19">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>       
                 </StartTime>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will the startdate always be in this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`? If yes, what is the purpose of your testing for string-length? If not, what other formats are possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `callinfo/startdate` template to:

```
<xsl:template match="callinfo/startdate">
    <StartTime>
        <xsl:variable name="StartTime">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., ' '), 'T', substring-after(., ' '))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="startTimeSize" select = "string-length(.)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize = 19">
            <xsl:value-of select="$StartTime"/>.00+00:00
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize = 33">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($StartTime,0,24)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($StartTime,28,7)"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$startTimeSize != 33 and $startTimeSize != 19">
            <xsl:value-of select="$StartTime"/>
        </xsl:if>       
    </StartTime>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: xsl:value-of as a child of xsl:variable is bad style. Simpler here is `<xsl:variable name="StartTime" select="translate(., ' ', 'T')"/>`.